# Restore mongo collection from backup to existing collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

"I have a MongoDB 6 database named 'xyz' with a collection called 'abc' on one server. I'd like to create a backup of this 'xyz' database with its 'abc' collection from another server and then restore it on a new server. I'm concerned about whether the restore process will overwrite my existing data in the 'xyz' database's 'abc' collection or if it will add the new data from the old server while preserving the existing data. Has anyone here had experience with this type of MongoDB backup and restore process?"

Comment: There are several [MongoDB Database Tools](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/) for importing/exporting.  You can read the details in the docs.

Comment: See documentation: *mongorestore can create a new database or add data to an existing database. However, mongorestore performs inserts only and does not perform updates.*